# Laravel mysql multiple operations with one DB instance

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5

As far as I understand, each `DB::` in Laravel (I use 5.2, if that matters) basically opens new connection and closes it when operation is finished.

The question is, is there any possibility to create one `DB` instance and do n operations using it? Something like native php, where you open connection and close it manually after everything is done.

Like

```
$conn = DB;
$users = $conn->table('users')->get();
$bills = $conn->table('bills')->lists('id');
/* something happens */
unset($conn);
```

Or something of this type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DB transactions

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    $users = DB::table('users')->get();
    $bills = DB::table('bills')->lists('id');
});
```

More here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#database-transactions

Comment: is there a possibility to commit part of the data in process? or somehow avoid the necessity to either commit or rollback everything?

Comment: I can't tell for sure. Everything happens within the transaction.

Comment: @Yawning Milk You don't need to commit manually, if the closure completes without error then the transaction will be committed. If you want to commit part of the way, just use two transactions.